# Determine if object is any Predicate<T>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates, types

I've got an `IList<Delegate>` that contains some `Func<bool>`s and some `Predicate<T>`s, where `T` varies. I later need to sort out which of these items are `Predicate<T>`s, but don't want to close the door to adding other `Delegate` types to the list later, so I do not want to do this by identifying objects by `!(current_delegate is Func<bool>)`.

The highest abstraction below `Predicate<T>` is `MulticastDelegate`, which seems unhelpful (would need a non-generic `Predicate` type under `Predicate<T>`), and identifying the presence of the generic parameter is also useless given the other generic `Delegate`s that may be present in the list.

The only other thing I've considered is checking the `Name` of the `Type`. To me, string comparison is a near-smell, but maybe that is the is the best and/or only way -- you tell me.

**What is the best way to definitively determine that an `object` is any `Predicate<T>` without knowing the type of `T`?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
obj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Predicate<>)
```

Comment: Perfection. One of those things that I'm probably now going to find a good use for at least weekly.

Comment: Yeah, but be prepared to catch the `InvalidOperationException` that will be thrown for nongeneric delegate types--which sounds like they might be a future possibility. To avoid the hassle, check `Type.IsGenericType` before calling this method.

Answer (score 2):

```
Predicate<int> pred = ...;
var isPreidcate = pred.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Predicate<>);
```

On another note, if you have a generic list, you shoulnd't need to check the types in it. You may want to rethink your design if you need to check for specific types within a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list of special classes which wrap your delegates and provide additional sorting information. So you'll indirectly solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks; the list is populated by passing lambda expressions, which would add significant complexity to implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work well enough:

```
public static bool IsPredicate(object obj) {
    var ty = obj.GetType();
    var invoke = ty.GetMethod("Invoke");
    return invoke != null && invoke.ReturnType == typeof(bool);
}
```

The trick will be when you actually want to call the function, you will need to use reflection.

Here are some tests:

```
Func<bool> is pred? True
Func<int, bool> is pred? True
Predicate<int> is pred? True
Func<int> is pred? False
```